# Magento "Tell a Friend " redirects to 404 page inside tab

Tags: php, magento, friend, tell

I have showed "Tell a Friend " form in tabs on product detail page using the code below

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
          <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
     <alias>send-friend</alias>
     <title>Send Friends</title>
     <block>sendfriend/send</block>
     <template>sendfriend/send.phtml</template>
          </action>     
    </block>
```

And I have enabled allow guest to "Yes" from backend . But on submitting the form it redirects to 404 page. The default way of sending email works fine outside the tab but inside tab it doesnot work. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

If it's sending you to the proper url, whether or not you're coming from a tab, you should expect it to work the same way.

I just resolved my 404 error by

- Enabling Send To Friend inside Configuration > System > Advanced
- Setting "Enabled", "Default Template", "Allow Guests", "Cookie (unsafe)" inside Configuration > Catalog > Email to a Friend

The url I get sent to is http://www.example.com/sendfriend/product/send/id/14530/

My guess is that it's an issue in your template, somewhere.